# Have two bootstrap tabs on same page. How do I add two different css styles to both active tabs

Tags: css, tabs

I have two bootstrap tabs on same page, for one active tab i have a background and text Color property now the same styles are getting applied to other tab since both have common class .active. I want different styles for both active tabs. How to do that

I tried giving custom class to active tabs but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving same class, try to give them different `id`. Why not class you ask, because `id` is meant for single element whereas class is meant for group of elements. To access id you use `#`. Let's say your first id is named as id1 then you will select it like `#id1`.

Hope this helps.